# How can I access SCSS colors vars in a Vue template's javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

In my application, I have a component Notification. I call notifications in other components by the mixin method `toast('message to display', 'color-variable')`. What I want to achieve is that my Notification component has a background color of 'color-variable'. The problem is color vars are set in a scss file. From the scss code, I can get them by using function `color('color-name')`, however, I don't know how to dynamically use that scss function from the javascript of my vue template.

I tried to achieve this by `:style="{'background-color':` color(${notification.status})`}"`, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to access scss vars as data in a view template?

Comment: just create utility class for this colors and use this class in components. you can do it by for loop in sass file and crate class for colors like .bg-color--red etc. then you can using this class in your components.

Comment: sass is pre compiled to css so in your app you don't have access to this variable  and functions because they are not exist on css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export sass vars into your vue.js app. I find this to be highly effective for theming variables especially. Here is an example of a color var setup I have in one of my apps:

```css
$primaryShades: (
  50: #f5fef9,
  100: #e6fcf1,
  200: #d5fae8,
  300: #c4f8df,
  400: #b8f7d8,
  500: #abf5d1,
  600: #a4f4cc,
  700: #9af2c6,
  800: #91f0c0,
  900: #80eeb5,
  A100: #fff,
  A200: #fff,
  A400: #fff,
  A700: #f6fffa
);

$primary: map-get($primaryShades, 500);

$primary_100: map-get($primaryShades, 100);
$primary_200: map-get($primaryShades, 200);
$primary_300: map-get($primaryShades, 300);
$primary_400: map-get($primaryShades, 400);
$primary_500: map-get($primaryShades, 500);
$primary_600: map-get($primaryShades, 600);
$primary_700: map-get($primaryShades, 700);
$primary_800: map-get($primaryShades, 800);
$primary_900: map-get($primaryShades, 900);


$error: #ef9a9a;

$success: #76c078;

/* stylelint-disable -- exports for js don't need/want style rules applied to this block. */
:export {
  primary: $primary;
  error: $error;
  success: $success;
}

@each $color, $value in $primaryShades {
  :export {
    primary#{$color}: $value;
  }
}

/* stylelint-enable */
```

Then if you would like global access you can import them in to your app via a global mixin:

```js
import colors from './assets/scss/colors_vars.scss';// edit for your location

// in some global mixin
Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return {
      colors: colors
    };
  }
})
```

Finally access them in your code like you would any other data bit:

```js
toast('message to display', this.colors.error) // in this example I am applying the error color
```

So you can then write whatever logic you need to make the right color happen when you need it to.

```js
computed: {
   notificationColor() {
     if(errorCondition) {
      return this.color.error
    }
     if(successCondition) {
      return this.color.success
    }
  }
}
```

If you have color arrays defined, you can see with the scss block how to loop over them and export. To access primary shade 50 as an example would be `this.colors.primary50`. So you can keep your color setting in your styles, but use them in your js seamlessly and change them all in one place.