# how to avoid hard coded colors in vue using typescript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a component in vue using typescript. And there I have a function to choose color:

```
chooseColor() {
      return (
        {
          color1: '#67213a',
          color2: '#909aaa',
        }[this.type] || '#67213a'
      );
    },
```

Also I have a color.scss function and I define the same colors there:

```
$color1: '#67213a',
$color2: '#909aaa',
```

So how can I avoid hard coded colors in my function?

Comment: can't you return a class instead of a color? Can you include how the function is used?

Comment: Thats how I am using <color-picker :color="chooseColor"/>

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/q/64874826/3462319?

Comment: This doesn't even have a little to do with typescript. Tags updated.

Comment: That object is a constant. It should not be recreated over and over and over in this function. Also, that fallback color should be a constant. At the very least you want this code to be `chooseColor(name = this.colorName) { return COLOR_MAP[name] ?? DEFAULT_COLOR; }` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```css
:root {
  --color1: #67213a;
  --color2: #909aaa;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div :style="{backgroundColor:`var(${chosen})`}">
            something
        </div>
        <button @click="setColor('--color1')">setColor</button>
    </div>

    <script type="module">
        import Vue from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.esm.browser.js"
        const vue = new Vue({
            el: "#root",
            data() {
                return {
                    chosen: '--color2',
                }
            },
            methods: {
                setColor(color) {
                    this.chosen = color
                },
            },
        })
    </script>
</body>
```